# I am getting a syntax error while writing a code in Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am getting a Syntax error in the following code:

```
btn+ = Button(
    btnrow1,
    text = "+",
    font = ("Verdana", 22),
    relief = GROOVE,
    Border = 0,
   )
btn+.pack(side = LEFT, expand = True, fill = "both")
```

Comment: That is indeed syntactically invalid, you can't have a `+` in a variable name. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers.

Comment: Variable names can contain: letters (upper or lower case), underscores (`_`) and digits (but not a digit as the first character). This is in common with many other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'+' is not allowed in variable defining.

Instead of btn+, make it button_plus or smth like that.